# How to call or defer java script tag at the last of page

Tags: javascript

When i see the calls for external script , The call is going and the script is called at the top. what i need is to call the script at the last of the page load.

I tried with attribute= defer="defer"
Also, I tried it loading asyncronously. But, after the complete page loads , only the script executes displaying its content and the rest of page disappears.

The issue is in the external Script as it contains more inner calls to scripts which have a whole div structure and the related styles.

So, I am struck here.

Comment: please give us http://jsfiddle.net or some source code

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to place the `script` at the end of the dom (just before `</body>`)?

Comment: Yes, I tried adding it before </body> tag. But as the script call has more inner calls of scripts,It executes only the script and the page gets disappeared.